# Finding the correct UTM zone for set of coordinate in R

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, r, wgs84, utm

I have a set of points (coordinates) which is in `WGS84 UTM` but I don't know the zone to convert it to Lat/Lng to be able to put it on the map !

I was wondering if there is a way of extracting the `zone` out of such data in r ?
Something like a range of values per UTM zones that can be checked ?!

Here my data sample :

```
df = structure(list(easting = c(621989.509236046, 619894.640597788, 
620440.740921878, 616379.251476303, 622321.807784562), northing = c(7234695.01739055, 
7232761.62687717, 7247432.24908296, 7248460.9079911, 7255937.80103861
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

PS: For this particular data set , I know the `utm zone` is 34N and therefore I can convert it :

```
spTransform((SpatialPoints(cbind(df$easting,df$northing), 
                                          proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=34 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"))),CRS("+proj=longlat"))@coords
```

Comment: Where on Earth should the data be situated?

Comment: @Erik, What do you mean ? this is my question : If I know the UTM zone , I could project it on the map easily ! 
I would like to know if I could find the UTM zone knowing that my data is in `wgs84 UTM` format

Comment: There is no difference in UTM coordinates from zone to zone, so effectively each point is one of 120 different points. If you don't know where it's supposed to be, there's no way to tell.

Comment: @Vince, SO this means if I don't know the `UTM` zone, I can not calculate it even if I know the data is in `wgs84 utm` format ?

Comment: It could be any one of the UTM zones. But you can narrow it down if you know, for example, that it's Europe. Even more if you know it's Liechtenstein.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The points could be in any of the 60 northern UTM zones. I think it has to be northern because the Y coords are positive, but I may be wrong. Anyway...

Convert points to spatial data set:

```
library(sf)
sdf = st_as_sf(df, coords=1:2)
```

We'll try these 60 EPSG codes for the UTM WGS84 zones:

```
zones = 32601:32660
```

Loop over zones, assign CRS, convert, return spatial data frame with crs, bind into one:

```
transformed = lapply(zones, 
  function(crs){
    sdf$crs = crs
    st_crs(sdf)=crs
    return(st_transform(sdf, 4326))
    })

allt = do.call(rbind, transformed)
```

Then we can plot:

```
library(mapview)
mapview(allt)
```

[image]

Is it Iceland? If so you know the zone must be the one that goes here (32627):

[image]

But you said it was zone 34 so between Sweden and Finland?

[image]

So in general an unknown zone can't be located better than any of these 60 locations. Once you know the rough location you can have a much better idea. The best thing to do is ask the person who gave you the data for the real metadata!